# Exporting canvas drawings to html format

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to make a drawing application that will export into html/css/javascript. Using [this](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful) tutorial as the basis for the drawing part, I want to be able to take all of the rectangles in the `this.shapes = []` and export the code so that it doesn't require the canvas, and can have regular html attributes added to them, like buttons or text fields. What should I export it to? Is there a combination of html/css/javascript or something else that I should be looking at?

A basic example of the app would be, draw a square, make it red, select an option to make it a text field, add some text to it. Upon exporting it you would get some html element some text. I'm just not sure how to save things like location of the shape and text, color, and so on.

Comment: As far as I know, you're going to have to come up with your own algorithm for analysing the state of the canvas and processing it into sensible html. This is going to be a pretty mammoth task, not necessarily impossible but definitely very large. I think you'll have to allow people to create div rectangles etc and give them some way of indicating how the elements are nested. Positioning is however going to be very hard.
You have unfortunately ran into the problem that many graphical webdesign tools have- constructing html in a gooey is very awkward and difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You could export canvas to base64. But then only convert it to an image.